# Get the date a feature class was last modified using SQL?

Tags: sql, esri-geodatabase

I have an oracle database that contains versioned and non versioned feature classes.

Each feature class has editor tracking enabled, so when a feature is added or updated, I can see the date the change occurred, and from that can calculate the maxdate of that featureclass to get when it was last "modified".
However if a feature is deleted that information is not captured within the featureclass (therefore the last modified date will be incorrect). I know that if it is versioned the OBJECTID is captured in the deletes table, but there is no date field (that i am aware of).

Is there a SQL way of getting the last modified date of a feature class, whether it is versioned or non versioned and regardless of whether it is an insert, update or delete.

Comment: You could create a table with a row or each table, and add a trigger to the business table to update that row on INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.  There will be a performance penalty for this trigger.  And then you have to decide whether a versioned edit that does not reach the the business table qualified as an edit, and add triggers to the A and D tables as well if so.

Comment: It looks like there are some interesting results when I google "oracle date of last dml". Have you tried searching that sort of thing?